# Is this a bug in the product mix problem (linear programming problem) incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-transformations, linear-programming

I am trying to work through this [product mix optimization problem](http://home.anadolu.edu.tr/~nila/PROGRAM/KILAVUZ/optimization%20modelling%20with%20lingo/Chapter6.pdf), and I cannot understand this part on the second page (page 100):

It says...

*The first 20 units of D and E produced per week can be sold at 4 dollars each, but all
made in excess of 20 can only be sold at 3 dollars each.*

And then later on, I see...

*Define two additional products $D_2$ and $E_2$, which sell for 3 dollars per unit.  What upper limits must then be placed on the sale of the original products D and E?*

And then in the table below that statement, for $D$ it shows that the *Number of units of $D$ produced in excess of 20 per week* as having $3 for the Profit Contribution per Unit.

It is confusing to me that it says $4$ in the first part?  And $3 dollars in the second part?  In my opinion, it seems like 4 is correct, and the table is wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the profit, you have to subtract the $1 cost to create the item.